In Active Directory, how to synchronize the members of a group automatically based on users attributes?
In Active Directory on premise, I would like to maintain distribution lists and security groups based on the attributes of the users, for instance the manager, the department, the city.

Windows does not provide this feature out of the box unfortunately, but it is relatively easy to implement as a Powershell script, which can run as a scheduled task.
Here is the file containing the corresponding function. It is called AD2DL as in "Active Directory To Distribution List", but it works with security groups as well.
AD2DL.ps1

# https://serverfault.com/questions/1161995/in-active-directory-how-to-synchronize-the-members-of-a-group-automatically-bas/1161996

function Sync-AD2DL {
    param (
        # Example AdGroupName: "MyGroup"
        [string]$AdGroupName,
        # Example filters:
        #   "*"
        #   "Department -eq 'IT'"
        #   "Department -like 'IT'"
        #   "Manager -eq 'someone' -or SamAccountName -eq 'someone'"
        #   "City -eq 'Berlin' -and SamAccountName -ne 'exception'"
        # See below for all properties
        [string]$Filter,
        # Example OrganisationalUnits: @("OU=Users,dc=domain,dc=tld")
        [string[]]$OrganisationalUnits
   )

    $expectedMembers = @()

    foreach($ou in $OrganisationalUnits)
    {
        $matchingUsers = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -Filter $filter

        # Filter out accounts that are disabled:
        $matchingUsers = $matchingUsers | Where { $_.Enabled }

        $expectedMembers += $matchingUsers
    }

    # Write-Host "expectedMembers=" $currentMembers

    $expectedNames = $expectedMembers | select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

    $currentMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $AdGroupName
    $currentNames = $currentMembers | select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
    $oldLength = $currentMembers.Length

    # Write-Host "currentMembers=" $currentMembers

    $usersToAdd = $expectedMembers | Where-Object { $currentNames -notcontains $_.DistinguishedName }

    foreach($user in $usersToAdd)
    {
        Write-Host "Adding " $user " to " $AdGroupName
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $AdGroupName -Members $user.samaccountname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    $usersToRemove = $currentMembers | Where-Object { $expectedNames -notcontains $_.DistinguishedName }

    foreach($user in $usersToRemove)
    {
        Write-Host "Removing " $user " from " $AdGroupName
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $AdGroupName -Members $user.samaccountname -Confirm:$false
    }

    $newLength = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $AdGroupName).Length
    Write-Host $AdGroupName " Added:" $usersToAdd.Length "  Removed:" $usersToRemove.Length "New size:" $newLength
}


# All user properties, for reference, retrieved with "Get-Member":
#
# AccountExpirationDate                 Property              System.DateTime AccountExpirationDate {get;set;}
# accountExpires                        Property              System.Int64 accountExpires {get;set;}
# AccountLockoutTime                    Property              System.DateTime AccountLockoutTime {get;set;}
# AccountNotDelegated                   Property              System.Boolean AccountNotDelegated {get;set;}
# AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption     Property              System.Boolean AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption {get;set;}
# AuthenticationPolicy                  Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection AuthenticationPolicy {get;set;}
# AuthenticationPolicySilo              Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection AuthenticationPolicySilo {get;set;}
# BadLogonCount                         Property              System.Int32 BadLogonCount {get;}
# badPasswordTime                       Property              System.Int64 badPasswordTime {get;set;}
# badPwdCount                           Property              System.Int32 badPwdCount {get;set;}
# c                                     Property              System.String c {get;set;}
# CannotChangePassword                  Property              System.Boolean CannotChangePassword {get;set;}
# CanonicalName                         Property              System.String CanonicalName {get;}
# Certificates                          Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection Certificates {get;set;}
# City                                  Property              System.String City {get;set;}
# CN                                    Property              System.String CN {get;}
# co                                    Property              System.String co {get;set;}
# codePage                              Property              System.Int32 codePage {get;set;}
# Company                               Property              System.String Company {get;set;}
# CompoundIdentitySupported             Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection CompoundIdentitySupported {get;set;}
# Country                               Property              System.String Country {get;set;}
# countryCode                           Property              System.Int32 countryCode {get;set;}
# Created                               Property              System.DateTime Created {get;}
# createTimeStamp                       Property              System.DateTime createTimeStamp {get;}
# Deleted                               Property              System.Boolean Deleted {get;}
# Department                            Property              System.String Department {get;set;}
# Description                           Property              System.String Description {get;set;}
# DisplayName                           Property              System.String DisplayName {get;set;}
# DistinguishedName                     Property              System.String DistinguishedName {get;set;}
# Division                              Property              System.String Division {get;set;}
# DoesNotRequirePreAuth                 Property              System.Boolean DoesNotRequirePreAuth {get;set;}
# dSCorePropagationData                 Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection dSCorePropagationData {get;}
# EmailAddress                          Property              System.String EmailAddress {get;set;}
# EmployeeID                            Property              System.String EmployeeID {get;set;}
# EmployeeNumber                        Property              System.String EmployeeNumber {get;set;}
# Enabled                               Property              System.Boolean Enabled {get;set;}
# Fax                                   Property              System.String Fax {get;set;}
# GivenName                             Property              System.String GivenName {get;set;}
# HomeDirectory                         Property              System.String HomeDirectory {get;set;}
# HomedirRequired                       Property              System.Boolean HomedirRequired {get;set;}
# HomeDrive                             Property              System.String HomeDrive {get;set;}
# homeMDB                               Property              System.String homeMDB {get;set;}
# HomePage                              Property              System.String HomePage {get;set;}
# HomePhone                             Property              System.String HomePhone {get;set;}
# Initials                              Property              System.String Initials {get;set;}
# instanceType                          Property              System.Int32 instanceType {get;}
# isDeleted                             Property              System.Boolean isDeleted {get;}
# KerberosEncryptionType                Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection KerberosEncryptionType {get;set;}
# l                                     Property              System.String l {get;set;}
# LastBadPasswordAttempt                Property              System.DateTime LastBadPasswordAttempt {get;}
# LastKnownParent                       Property              System.String LastKnownParent {get;}
# lastLogoff                            Property              System.Int64 lastLogoff {get;set;}
# lastLogon                             Property              System.Int64 lastLogon {get;set;}
# LastLogonDate                         Property              System.DateTime LastLogonDate {get;}
# lastLogonTimestamp                    Property              System.Int64 lastLogonTimestamp {get;set;}
# legacyExchangeDN                      Property              System.String legacyExchangeDN {get;set;}
# LockedOut                             Property              System.Boolean LockedOut {get;set;}
# lockoutTime                           Property              System.Int64 lockoutTime {get;set;}
# logonCount                            Property              System.Int32 logonCount {get;set;}
# LogonWorkstations                     Property              System.String LogonWorkstations {get;set;}
# mail                                  Property              System.String mail {get;set;}
# mailNickname                          Property              System.String mailNickname {get;set;}
# Manager                               Property              System.String Manager {get;set;}
# mDBUseDefaults                        Property              System.Boolean mDBUseDefaults {get;set;}
# MemberOf                              Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection MemberOf {get;}
# MNSLogonAccount                       Property              System.Boolean MNSLogonAccount {get;set;}
# MobilePhone                           Property              System.String MobilePhone {get;set;}
# Modified                              Property              System.DateTime Modified {get;}
# modifyTimeStamp                       Property              System.DateTime modifyTimeStamp {get;}
# mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid                 Property              System.Byte[] mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid {get;set;}
# msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes         Property              System.Int32 msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes {get;set;}
# msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed    Property              System.Int32 msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed {get;}
# msExchArchiveQuota                    Property              System.Int64 msExchArchiveQuota {get;set;}
# msExchArchiveWarnQuota                Property              System.Int64 msExchArchiveWarnQuota {get;set;}
# msExchCalendarLoggingQuota            Property              System.Int32 msExchCalendarLoggingQuota {get;set;}
# msExchDumpsterQuota                   Property              System.Int32 msExchDumpsterQuota {get;set;}
# msExchDumpsterWarningQuota            Property              System.Int32 msExchDumpsterWarningQuota {get;set;}
# msExchELCMailboxFlags                 Property              System.Int32 msExchELCMailboxFlags {get;set;}
# msExchHomeServerName                  Property              System.String msExchHomeServerName {get;set;}
# msExchMailboxGuid                     Property              System.Byte[] msExchMailboxGuid {get;set;}
# msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor       Property              System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor {get;set;}
# msExchMobileMailboxFlags              Property              System.Int32 msExchMobileMailboxFlags {get;set;}
# msExchPoliciesIncluded                Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection msExchPoliciesIncluded {get;set;}
# msExchRBACPolicyLink                  Property              System.String msExchRBACPolicyLink {get;set;}
# msExchRecipientDisplayType            Property              System.Int32 msExchRecipientDisplayType {get;set;}
# msExchRecipientTypeDetails            Property              System.Int64 msExchRecipientTypeDetails {get;set;}
# msExchTextMessagingState              Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection msExchTextMessagingState {get;set;}
# msExchUMDtmfMap                       Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection msExchUMDtmfMap {get;set;}
# msExchUserAccountControl              Property              System.Int32 msExchUserAccountControl {get;set;}
# msExchUserCulture                     Property              System.String msExchUserCulture {get;set;}
# msExchVersion                         Property              System.Int64 msExchVersion {get;set;}
# msExchWhenMailboxCreated              Property              System.DateTime msExchWhenMailboxCreated {get;set;}
# Name                                  Property              System.String Name {get;}
# nTSecurityDescriptor                  Property              System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity nTSecurityDescriptor {get;set;}
# ObjectCategory                        Property              System.String ObjectCategory {get;}
# ObjectClass                           Property              System.String ObjectClass {get;set;}
# ObjectGUID                            Property              System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e0...
# objectSid                             Property              System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier objectSid {get;}
# Office                                Property              System.String Office {get;set;}
# OfficePhone                           Property              System.String OfficePhone {get;set;}
# Organization                          Property              System.String Organization {get;set;}
# OtherName                             Property              System.String OtherName {get;set;}
# PasswordExpired                       Property              System.Boolean PasswordExpired {get;set;}
# PasswordLastSet                       Property              System.DateTime PasswordLastSet {get;set;}
# PasswordNeverExpires                  Property              System.Boolean PasswordNeverExpires {get;set;}
# PasswordNotRequired                   Property              System.Boolean PasswordNotRequired {get;set;}
# POBox                                 Property              System.String POBox {get;set;}
# PostalCode                            Property              System.String PostalCode {get;set;}
# PrimaryGroup                          Property              System.String PrimaryGroup {get;}
# primaryGroupID                        Property              System.Int32 primaryGroupID {get;set;}
# PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount  Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount {get;...
# ProfilePath                           Property              System.String ProfilePath {get;set;}
# ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion       Property              System.Boolean ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion {get;set;}
# proxyAddresses                        Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection proxyAddresses {get;set;}
# pwdLastSet                            Property              System.Int64 pwdLastSet {get;set;}
# SamAccountName                        Property              System.String SamAccountName {get;set;}
# sAMAccountType                        Property              System.Int32 sAMAccountType {get;set;}
# ScriptPath                            Property              System.String ScriptPath {get;set;}
# sDRightsEffective                     Property              System.Int32 sDRightsEffective {get;}
# ServicePrincipalNames                 Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection ServicePrincipalNames {get;set;}
# showInAddressBook                     Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection showInAddressBook {get;set;}
# SID                                   Property              System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier SID {get;set;}
# SIDHistory                            Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection SIDHistory {get;}
# SmartcardLogonRequired                Property              System.Boolean SmartcardLogonRequired {get;set;}
# sn                                    Property              System.String sn {get;set;}
# st                                    Property              System.String st {get;set;}
# State                                 Property              System.String State {get;set;}
# StreetAddress                         Property              System.String StreetAddress {get;set;}
# Surname                               Property              System.String Surname {get;set;}
# telephoneNumber                       Property              System.String telephoneNumber {get;set;}
# Title                                 Property              System.String Title {get;set;}
# TrustedForDelegation                  Property              System.Boolean TrustedForDelegation {get;set;}
# TrustedToAuthForDelegation            Property              System.Boolean TrustedToAuthForDelegation {get;set;}
# UseDESKeyOnly                         Property              System.Boolean UseDESKeyOnly {get;set;}
# userAccountControl                    Property              System.Int32 userAccountControl {get;set;}
# userCertificate                       Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection userCertificate {get;set;}
# UserPrincipalName                     Property              System.String UserPrincipalName {get;set;}
# uSNChanged                            Property              System.Int64 uSNChanged {get;}
# uSNCreated                            Property              System.Int64 uSNCreated {get;}
# whenChanged                           Property              System.DateTime whenChanged {get;}
# whenCreated                           Property              System.DateTime whenCreated {get;}
# wWWHomePage                           Property              System.String wWWHomePage {get;set;}


Here is the main script. There is one line for each group to synchronize. Put it in the same directory as the script above.
AD2DL-Sync-All.ps1


. $PSScriptRoot\AD2DL.ps1

$OrganisationalUnits = @(
    "OU=Users,dc=domain,dc=tld"
)


Sync-AD2DL -OrganisationalUnits $OrganisationalUnits  -AdGroupName 'All-Senior-Staff-Members' -filter "Title -eq 'Senior staff member'"

Here is a BAT help script that you can call as scheduled task, for instance twice a day. Put it in the same directory:
AD2DL-Sync-All.bat

@echo off
set ownpath=%~dp0
cd %ownpath%
powershell.exe -command "& '.\AD2DL-Sync-All.ps1'"

